# Is it possible to get --exclude-ext work only for some specific directories?

Tags: cloc

I need to exclude *.c files only from some specific directory/sub_directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cloc does not have a built-in way to do that.  You can exclude all *.c, or exclude a specific dir/subdir, but not exclude *.c only within a dir/subdir.

A two-step solution comes to mind:  you can make a list of files you want to exclude then pass that list file in to cloc with `--exclude-list-file`, for example,

```
    find dir/subdir -type f -name "*.c" > dont_want_these.txt
    cloc --exclude-list-file dont_want_these.txt dir
```